# Get font attributes in swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4

I've migrated project from swift 3 to swift 4 and cannot find a info how to get a font attribute from a `UIFontDescriptor`. Here is the code which works perfect in swift 3 :

```
 @objc convenience init(myCoder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        if let fontDescriptor = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "UIFontDescriptor") as? UIFontDescriptor {
            if let fontAttribute = fontDescriptor.fontAttributes["NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute"] as? String {
                var fontName = ""
                switch fontAttribute {
                case "CTFontRegularUsage":
                    fontName = Roboto.regular.rawValue
                case "CTFontEmphasizedUsage", "CTFontBoldUsage":
                    fontName = Roboto.bold.rawValue
                default:
                    fontName = Roboto.regular.rawValue
                }
                self.init(name: fontName, size: fontDescriptor.pointSize)!
            }
            else {
                self.init(myCoder: aDecoder)
            }
        }
        else {
            self.init(myCoder: aDecoder)
        }
    }
```

But In swift 4 the line :

```
if let fontAttribute = fontDescriptor.fontAttributes["NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute"] as? String
```

has an error : `Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'`.
Any ideas how can I change it ?

Thanks!

Comment: Here are the docs, with the Swift 4 changes highlighted. Notice anything? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifontdescriptor?changes=latest_minor

Comment: Also, what are you trying to do? If you're trying to support dynamic type with a custom font, there's a whole new totally supported way to do that. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifontmetrics

Comment: @noname, would you share how you resolved the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to treat your custom font as a dynamic type font. The supported way to do that in iOS 11 is to use [UIFontMetrics](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifontmetrics).

Comment: Would you share an actual example of how you would impliment the new UIFontMetrics?  I tried changing his line from `if let fontAttribute = fontDescriptor.fontAttributes["NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute"] as? String {` to `if let fontAttribute = fontDescriptor.AttributeName {` as mentioned in one of the links you shared (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifontdescriptor.attributename?changes=latest_minor) but had no luck..

Comment: my issue is exactly the same as the OP's.  Posting another question would be unnecessary and rightfully marked as a duplicate.  I was kindly asking if you could provide some actual code to support your answer rather than just a link

Comment: @Rbar I don't know what _you_ are doing. What I know is that UIFontMetrics lets you get the scaled font for _any_ font based on the user's dynamic type size preferences, which is what the OP seemed to be trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

```
let font: UIFont

let fontAttribute = UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName("NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute")

let fontUsageAttribute = font.fontDescriptor.fontAttributes[fontAttribute] as? String
```

Answer (score 2):

This work for me, creating a static value nsctFontUIUsage for `NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute` to then use it in `fontDescriptor.fontAttributes[.nsctFontUIUsage]`:

```
extension UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName {
    static let nsctFontUIUsage = UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName(rawValue: "NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute")
}

extension UIFont {
    @objc convenience init(myCoder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        guard
            let fontDescriptor = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "UIFontDescriptor") as? UIFontDescriptor,
            let fontAttribute = fontDescriptor.fontAttributes[.nsctFontUIUsage] as? String else {
                self.init(myCoder: aDecoder)
                return
        }
        var fontName = ""
        switch fontAttribute {

        case "CTFontRegularUsage":
            fontName = Resources.Fonts.Weight.regular

        case "CTFontEmphasizedUsage", "CTFontBoldUsage":
            fontName = Resources.Fonts.Weight.semibold

        case "CTFontObliqueUsage":
            fontName = Resources.Fonts.Weight.italic

        default:
            fontName = Resources.Fonts.Weight.light
        }
        self.init(name: fontName, size: fontDescriptor.pointSize)!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Be sure all your Project / Target Build Settings show Swift Language Version 4.x (4.0 for now). Without this set, the new UIFontDescriptor values won't be available. Note: a project with multiple targets may misbehave depending on which target you have selected and the Swift version specified for that target. To avoid, be sure all targets are updated to Swift 4.0.

2) Access a specific UIFontAttribute using the built in static types, paying attention to the expected return types.

For a UIFontAttribute with an optional NSString return type:

`let fontAttribute = fontDescriptor.object(forKey: .face) as? String`

or in your example, where no built-in static types exist:

`let fontAttribute = fontDescriptor.object(forKey: UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName(rawValue: "NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute")) as? String`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Solution. Work for me

```
 @objc convenience init(myCoder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    if let fontDescriptor = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "UIFontDescriptor") as? UIFontDescriptor {

           let fontAttribute = UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName("NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute")  
        if let fontAttribute = fontDescriptor.fontAttributes[fontAttribute] as? String {

           var fontName = ""
            switch fontAttribute {
            case "CTFontRegularUsage":
                fontName = Roboto.regular.rawValue
            case "CTFontEmphasizedUsage", "CTFontBoldUsage":
                fontName = Roboto.bold.rawValue
            default:
                fontName = Roboto.regular.rawValue
            }
            self.init(name: fontName, size: fontDescriptor.pointSize)!
        }
        else {
            self.init(myCoder: aDecoder)
        }
    }
    else {
        self.init(myCoder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```